# Set tabBar Item selected color white and not the default blue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

For some reason the tab bar selector color won't change even though I changed image tint. Any Ideas?

Comment: Not unless you give more details about the code you're using, any errors you see logged, what doc you're referring to...

Comment: Did you change the `selectedImageTintColor`

Comment: Sorry this one here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UITabBar.html

Comment: I have not tried that I assume I put it in the viewDidLoad right?

Comment: I did notice selectedImageTintColor is Deprecated in iOS 8.0.

Comment: I am basically trying to change the default blue color of a selected tabBarItem to white.